# Unable to get value submitted from Jquery post in Struts2 action

Tags: java, jquery, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am new struts and I am not sure what i am missing here. When I submit this form all the fields are null in the struts action class. I have added an interceptor "adminHomeInterceptor" to check whether the user is admin or not, This works fine when I remove that interceptor-ref. But I have to check for all request whether the user is admin, so cant remove that interceptor. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Here is my jsp.

```
    <s:form id="vendorRegister" action="addvendor" method="post" theme="simple">
        <label for="username" class="formLabel">Username/Email</label>
        <s:textfield name="userName" id="txtUname" cssClass="small ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br />
        <label for="phone" class="formLabel">Phone</label>
        <s:textfield name="phone" id="txtPhone" cssClass="small ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br />
        <label for="mobile" class="formLabel">Mobile</label>
        <s:textfield name="mobile" id="txtMobile" cssClass="small ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /><br />
    <s:submit id="btnRegister" cssClass="button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="Add Vendor" />
</s:form>
```

This is a dynamically loaded form.

```
$("#btnRegister").live("click",(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var uname = $( "#txtUname" ),
    phone =  $("#txtPhone"),
    mobile = $("#txtMobile"),   
    if ( // Validation Codes ) {
        $("#btnRegister").attr("disabled", true);
        var url = "../addvendor";
        $.post( url , $("#vendorRegister").serialize(), function(data){
            alert("inside");
        });
    }
}));
```

My Strust2 Action Class

```
public class VendorAction extends ActionSupport{

    private int phone;
    private long mobile;
    private String userName;

    public int getPhone() {
         return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(int phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public long getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(long mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String recordVendor(){
        System.out.println(userName);
        System.out.println(mobile);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Here is my struts.xml file

```
     <package name="admin" namespace="/admin" extends="json-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="adminHomeInterceptor" class="org.admin.interceptors.AdminHomeInterceptor" />
    </interceptors>
    <action name="addvendor" class="org.vendor.action.VendorAction" method="recordVendor">
        <interceptor-ref name="adminHomeInterceptor" />
        <result type="json" /> 
    </action>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured *only one interceptor for your action*, so no other interceptors are applied to the request.

```
<action name="addvendor" class="org.vendor.action.VendorAction" method="recordVendor">
  <interceptor-ref name="adminHomeInterceptor" />
  <result type="json" /> 
</action>
```

Instead, you must create an interceptor stack and then reference that for your action (or all actions).

### Example

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="adminHomeInterceptor" class="org.admin.interceptors.AdminHomeInterceptor" />
  <interceptor-stack name="exampleDefaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="adminHomeInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
      <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
      <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
      <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
  </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

Then change the `interceptor-ref` for your action to:

```
<interceptor-ref name="exampleDefaultStack"/>
```

Alternatively, you can apply this stack to all actions by default by including the following in the package section:

```
<default-interceptor-ref name="exampleDefaultStack"/>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I have one more doubt, should we refer all these interceptors inside every action every actions.

Comment: No, in general you should define one stack (per package) and make it the default for all actions in that package. If you have multiple "groups" of actions, divide them into packages in the struts.xml. You can create a custom interceptor stack for an individual action, but it should be a rare occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `struts2-json` plugin .
If you are using it . 
You have to include

```
<interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor" />  in struts.xml
```

and define result type json like this at package level

```
<result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" default="false" />
```

Otherewise getters/setters will not work with JSOn you are sending through json.

Comment: `<result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" default="false" />` should not be withing your `<action>` tags but in your `<package>`.

Comment: Sorry Guys I had an interceptor within the that action, when I removed that Interceptor its working fine. But I need that Interceptor to check the user is admin or not, so cant remove that interceptor.

Comment: Check my answer for an explanation of why your custom interceptor was breaking this and how to fix it.

Comment: @nmc . i meant package level only. my bad of not making it clear. !